# Android Studio 'Default' theme mixed up with 'Dracula' theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I have kind of a strange problem trying to select 'Default' theme to my Android Studio. Choosing it, I supposed to get a white color theme but it remains half black and half white. like in the pic. Could I change it somehow?
[image]

I selected it as needed:
[image]

Comment: To Help You I recreated your issue in mine

Comment: Did you try restarting Android Studio?

Comment: No use I hope.... I restarted

Comment: @AtifFarrukh I even restarted PC and no effect...

Comment: File --> Settings --> Apperance & Behaviour --> Theme -- > InteliJ and click Apply

Worked For me

Comment: @VasileDoe It Worked or not....

Answer (score 2):

File --> Settings --> Apperance & Behaviour --> Apperance -- > change Theme to InteliJ and click
 Apply

[image]