# Android Studio Darcula Theme Error

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, android-theme

I am new to Android (working from last 1 month). Today when I open my Android Studio (Version 3.1.4) I noticed a strange thing. My Darcula theme got mixed with Default Theme and now it looks like this

[image: Android Studio Darcula Theme Mixed Up]

I tried to change Theme back to Default(and InteliJ also)  and then switching to Darcula but no success. Also tried to restart my Laptop and Android Studio but the result is same
I also tried the answers of the similar post to this but no success

[Android Studio 'Default' theme mixed up with 'Dracula' theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758672/android-studio-default-theme-mixed-up-with-dracula-theme)

How to Solve the issue I am Using Windows 10 and Android Studio Version 3.1.4

P.S. I Don't want to reinstall my Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You might be tried to change Settings > Colors&Fonts > Scheme like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaxsL.png

Try to edit Settings > Appearances > Theme

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnuKL.png

Comment: Actually, this issue came automatically. Already tried Settings > Appearances > Theme